# Unit in cyclotomic field

Tags: nt.number-theory, roots-of-unity, cyclotomic-fields

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\zeta$ be a primitive $n$-th root of unity. I want to know for which $n$ the element $1+2(\zeta+\zeta^{-1})$ is a unit in the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta]$. Can anything be said about that?

Comment: No, e.g. take $n=6$; then $\zeta+\zeta^{-1}=1$ and $1+2(\zeta+\zeta^{-1}) = 3$. Aside: this question is probably more appropriate for http://math.stackexchange.com .

Comment: @guest: Do you need to know for which $n$ you get a unit? In this case, the question probably isn't that easy. I believe this holds only for $n=3,4,7,10,24$.

Comment: @PeterMueller: Yes, I want to know for which $n$ this is a unit

Comment: How about computing the norms of $1+2(\zeta+\zeta^{-1})$ for small values of $n$ and looking up the resulting sequence in the OEIS?

Comment: The question is equivalent to "for which $n$ is $N_{{\mathbb Q}(\zeta_n)/{\mathbb Q}}(1 + 2(\zeta_n + \zeta_n^{-1})) = 1$?" Computing the norms for $n$ up to 100, it looks like the norm is comparatively small for smooth $n$. Perhaps one can prove a lower bound in terms of some data from the prime factorization of $n$?

Comment: PS: The sequence of norms is not in the OEIS (and the same is true of "3, 4, 7, 10, 24").

Comment: We have $1+2(\zeta+\zeta^{-1})=\frac2\zeta(\zeta-a)(\zeta-\bar a)$, where $a=(-1+i\sqrt{15})/4$ (notice that $|a|=1$, and $2a$ is an algebraic integer). Thus the norm is 1 iff $2^{\varphi(n)/2}|\Phi_n(a)|=1$. At least, this should mean that some $n$th root of unity is sufficiently close to $a$...

Answer (score 2):

This is only a partial answer: it reduces the question to another problem.

Taking up Ilya Bogdanov's comment, let $a$ be a root of $2x^2 + x + 2$.
Then (as he says) we are interested in the set of numbers $n$ such that
$2^{\varphi(n)/2} |\Phi_n(a)| = 1$. We note that
$t_n := (2^{n/2} |a^n - 1|)^2 = 2^{n+1} - \operatorname{Tr}(2a)^n$
satisfies the recurrence $$t_{n+3} = t_{n+2} - 2 t_{n+1} + 8 t_n$$
with initial values $t_0 = 0$, $t_1 = 5$, $t_2 = 15$.
Now the question is, for which $n$ is
$$N(n) := \prod_{d\mid n} t_d^{\mu(n/d)} = 1 \quad ?$$
**If** one could show that for large enough $n$, $t_n$ always has
a primitive prime divisor $p$ (meaning a prime $p$ such that $p$ divides 
$t_n$, but $p$ does not divide $t_m$ for any $1 \le m < n$), then it
would follow that $N(n) > 1$ for all large $n$ (since $p$ divides $N(n)$).
However, I am not aware of any general results on primitive prime divisors
of *ternary* recurrences. There are quite general statements for
*binary* recurrences, for example

> Bilu, Yu.; Hanrot, G.; Voutier, P. M.:
>   *Existence of primitive divisors of Lucas and Lehmer numbers.*
>   J. Reine Angew. Math. **539** (2001), 75-122.

where it is shown that in this case there is always a primitive prime
divisor when $n > 30$.

Proving a similar statement even for the specific sequence $(t_n)$ might
be hard.

Comment: This approach, if it doesn't finish the question, at least is a cheap test if there are more small exceptions. There aren't any for $n\le300000$.